# Compute aspx attribute value at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a DataSet that contains columns that related to enums in my application. I therefore extended the BoundField control to create a new control EnumBoundField. This will take the integer value held in the DataSet and display the description of the enum.

However I would like to add a property to the new control call EnumType and this would be of type System.Type.

e.g.

```
public Type EnumType{ get; set; }
```

In my aspx where I define the GridView I would like to use my control like:

```
<cust:EnumBoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="statusField" EnumType="<%= typeof(SystemStatus)%>" />
```

However the above results in the string '<%= typeof(SystemStatus)%>' being passed to my control. Do you know if it is possible to have the the type of Enum passed to the control at run time?

I want to make this control as reusable as possible so that I can reuse it on multiple columns by just passing in a different enum type.

Comment: I think what I want to do is allow the EnumType attribute to be set by a Scriptlet

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

the <%= %> syntax does not work as a databinding expression try <%# %>

Comment: Thanks ek_ny, I had already tried that but I get a Parser Error 
stating "Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event"

Comment: hmmm.. really... what exactly is <cust:EnumBoundField> ?